I want to train a resnet 50 model for an image clasification task, how do I modify the layers so that it accepts a 64x64 image?
I want to train a resnet 50 model for an image clasification task. The default model requires 224x224 images, my dataset has 64x64 images and it seems wasteful to first upscale them then train on that data.
How should I modify the layers so that it not only accepts the 64x64 image, but retains a decent size by the final layer, when it reaches the fully conected classification layer?
This is my keggle notebook: https://www.kaggle.com/code/cristiciorba/cv-resnet-lego-bricks

Padding might help. The dimensions of the image can be increased to 224x224 without losing any of its features.

maybe ask on similar portals DataScience or CrossValidated

Inspection
Let's inspect the effect of the resnet50 layers on your image for 224x224 and 64x64 resolutions by adding a hook to print the output shapes of each block:
import torch
from torchvision.models import resnet50, ResNet50_Weights


def add_hook(name, m):
    def forward_hook(module, input, output):
        print(f"{name} output shape:", output.shape)

    m.register_forward_hook(forward_hook)


resnet = resnet50(weights=ResNet50_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1)

for name, layer in resnet.named_children():
    add_hook(name, layer)

for dim in [224, 64]:
    print(f"Input dim: {dim}x{dim}")
    x = torch.randn(1, 3, dim, dim)
    _ = resnet(x)
    print()

which prints
Input dim: 224x224
conv1 output shape: torch.Size([1, 64, 112, 112])
bn1 output shape: torch.Size([1, 64, 112, 112])
relu output shape: torch.Size([1, 64, 112, 112])
maxpool output shape: torch.Size([1, 64, 56, 56])
layer1 output shape: torch.Size([1, 256, 56, 56])
layer2 output shape: torch.Size([1, 512, 28, 28])
layer3 output shape: torch.Size([1, 1024, 14, 14])
layer4 output shape: torch.Size([1, 2048, 7, 7])
avgpool output shape: torch.Size([1, 2048, 1, 1])
fc output shape: torch.Size([1, 1000])

Input dim: 64x64
conv1 output shape: torch.Size([1, 64, 32, 32])
bn1 output shape: torch.Size([1, 64, 32, 32])
relu output shape: torch.Size([1, 64, 32, 32])
maxpool output shape: torch.Size([1, 64, 16, 16])
layer1 output shape: torch.Size([1, 256, 16, 16])
layer2 output shape: torch.Size([1, 512, 8, 8])
layer3 output shape: torch.Size([1, 1024, 4, 4])
layer4 output shape: torch.Size([1, 2048, 2, 2])
avgpool output shape: torch.Size([1, 2048, 1, 1])
fc output shape: torch.Size([1, 1000])

Suggestions
Looking at the above, there are a few possibilities:
Maybe you could argue that the network was trained on 224x224 images, so it's better to work with this resolution. Then you could

Upsample to 224x224 as you've suggested.
Use trainable upsampling in the first few layers ie. with some additional convolutions. See here and here.

Alternatively, maybe it doesn't matter, just use it like this with 64x64 images. Then you could

Do nothing, maybe it's fine.
Remove the first few layers. You could argue that perhaps the first few layers have mostly learned to downsample anyway and aren't needed (as long as you plan to train more).
Probably the most common: remove the last few layers. You could argue that perhaps the last few layers are already sort of overfit to the task Resnet50 was trained on, so removing a few layers won't hurt much and you need to train more anyway.

A solution
You probably already know a few ways to remove the last layers, but I'll show one approach similar to your notebook:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torchvision.models import resnet50, ResNet50_Weights


class CustomResNet50(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(CustomResNet50, self).__init__()

        # Load the pretrained ResNet50 model
        self.resnet = resnet50(weights=ResNet50_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1)

        # don't use layer4 and the final fully connected layer
        self.backbone = nn.Sequential(
            self.resnet.conv1,
            self.resnet.bn1,
            self.resnet.relu,
            self.resnet.maxpool,
            self.resnet.layer1,
            self.resnet.layer2,
            self.resnet.avgpool,
        )

        # save memory
        del self.resnet

        # Define the new fully connected layers, maybe with a bit more compute
        # since we removed a few resnet layers
        self.head = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.LazyLinear(num_classes),
            nn.Dropout(0.2),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(num_classes),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(num_classes, num_classes),
            nn.Softmax(dim=1),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.backbone(x)
        return self.head(x)


num_classes = 200
dim = 64
model = CustomResNet50(num_classes=num_classes)

for name, layer in model.backbone.named_children():
    add_hook(name, layer)

for name, layer in model.head.named_children():
    add_hook(name, layer)

print(f"Input dim: {dim}x{dim}")
x = torch.randn(2, 3, dim, dim)
_ = model(x)

which gives these dimensions:
Input dim: 64x64
0 output shape: torch.Size([2, 64, 32, 32])
1 output shape: torch.Size([2, 64, 32, 32])
2 output shape: torch.Size([2, 64, 32, 32])
3 output shape: torch.Size([2, 64, 16, 16])
4 output shape: torch.Size([2, 256, 16, 16])
5 output shape: torch.Size([2, 512, 8, 8])
6 output shape: torch.Size([2, 512, 1, 1])
0 output shape: torch.Size([2, 512])
1 output shape: torch.Size([2, 200])
2 output shape: torch.Size([2, 200])
3 output shape: torch.Size([2, 200])
4 output shape: torch.Size([2, 200])
5 output shape: torch.Size([2, 200])
6 output shape: torch.Size([2, 200])

Note in my version:

I used nn.LazyLinear so you don't have to know the output dim of the backbone.
I added some more layers and a non-linearity to the head, I generally think this is a good idea. It also shouldn't hurt training time much since my version removes a lot of resnet layers.
It's probably not a good idea to have batch norm right after the linear layer that is doing the final output. In general, you want the final linear layer to not have anything after it (except possibly softmax, if you need that for the task).

None of these are really required for your question, but I thought I'd mention them.
